# render html page into gtkwindow

Tags: html, xhtml, gtk

how can i render HTML page into gtkwindow? say, i already have a downloaded/written HTML page. i want to render the content of that page in my gtk application. how can i implement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried both GtkHTML and [Webkit GTK](http://webkitgtk.org/) and my opinion is that Webkit is by far the stronger and more versatile of the two.